# Team City Version 9.0 hangs when running a PSEXEC command

Tags: teamcity, psexec

I am using Team City version 9 on a Windows Server 2012 machine.  I have a build step in my Team City project that uses psexec to runs a command line script on a remote computer.  The remote computer is Windows Server 2008 Standard 32-bit with SP2.  One line in the team city script is:

```
\\Aenyfs01\APPS1\Winstall75\PSTools\psexec.exe \\aewebsvctst4 \\aewebsvctst4\deployScripts\stopwebsite.cmd SCRIBE2QA1TEST -accepteula
```

When Team City gets to this line it starts running PSEXEC and then hangs.  I found another thread that said to use the -accepteula to suppress the license screen.

This line is using psexec to run a command script from the remote machine called aewebsvctst4.  I have psexec installed on that remote machine and ran psexec from the remote machine's windows explorer.  I got the license screen and clicked OK.

When I run this command from the team city build server machine it works fine.  But running in Team City just causes it to hang.

Here is the output from the build log in Team City:

```
[Step 2/3] C:\TeamCity_Working\Distribution\SCRIBE\Trunk>\\Aenyfs01\APPS1\Winstall75\PSTools\psexec.exe \\aewebsvctst4 \\aewebsvctst4\deployScripts\stopwebsite.cmd SCRIBE2QA1TEST -accepteula 
[18:05:55][Step 2/3] 
[18:05:55][Step 2/3] PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
[18:05:55][Step 2/3] Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
[18:05:55][Step 2/3] Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
[18:05:55][Step 2/3] 
[18:05:55][Step 2/3]
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks,
Glenn

Comment: it probably works for you and not TeamCity as it will be running under a different user account. What you can try is changing the TeamCity service (`services.msc -> 'Team City Server'`) to run as yourself instead of the SYSTEM account (you must restart the TC service after making the changes)

Comment: @wal -- close. Won't be TeamCity executing this, it will be the build agent so you need to whatever the that service is running as.

Comment: yes thanks for that. so the service name will be `TeamCity Build Agent` NOT 'TeamCity Server'

Comment: Hi, @wal I tried you suggestion and that didn't work.  Thank you for your suggestion.  Glenn

Comment: Hi Wyatt, I am not understanding your comment.  Can you please explain in a little more detail what you mean?  Thank you, Glenn

Comment: Wyatt, I figured out what you meant.  I did change the build agent to run under my account.  This still didn't work.  Thank you anyway.  Glenn

Comment: I got it fixed!  I read up further in the web and heard the psexec has a bug with Team City.  I was informed to use RemCom.  It has a similar syntax to psexec.  When I used RemCom everything worked!

Comment: @Glenn add your findings as an answer